# How to encode "a" to "6100"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encoding, nsstring

I need to encode a string into other format. Dose any one know what kind of encoding is this?
And how can I get the result using objective-c?

update 2013-10-22 02:23:49

I'm not sure if this is the best way. It solved my problem.

```
NSString *result_string = @"";
for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    int a = [string characterAtIndex:i];
    unsigned long long int theNumber = a;
    NSString *ascii_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llX", theNumber];

    //61 -> 6100, 4E03 -> 034E
    if (ascii_string.length == 2) {
        result_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@00", result_string, ascii_string];

    } else if (ascii_string.length == 4) {
        NSString *first2 = [ascii_string substringToIndex:2];
        NSString *last2 = [ascii_string substringFromIndex:2];
        result_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", result_string, last2, first2];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"length unknown: %d", ascii_string.length);
    }

}

return result_string;
```

Comment: That's two byte ascii in Hex format. 6100 is 0x61 0x00 which is the value for a in most text encodings

Comment: I'm betting little-endian UTF-16?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a punt and guess that you got that `6100` by looking at some data stream and that it's UTF-16 encoded in little endian.

So something like this would work:

```
NSString *str = @"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
// data can now be written to file or transmitted over the network.
```

Comment: Then how do I get the encoded NSString? e.g. the original string is @"hello", how do I get the @"680065006C006C006F00". It seems that the NSData can only decode to the original string.

Comment: Try decoding it as UTF-8 or ASCII, perhaps? Not sure if it will work, but worth a try.

Comment: @KaneRoss That isn't what you asked in your question, but the `NSData` -> `NSString` equivalent is `[initWithData:encoding:]`. Assuming this is little-endian UTF-16 of course.